# shadowing of functions in namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces, method-hiding

Suppose you have the following code

```
namespace a{
  struct S{};
  //void f(int){}
}

namespace b{
  struct T{};
}


struct X{};

void f(X){}
void f(b::T){}
void f(a::S){}



namespace a{
  void g(){

    S s;b::T t; 
    X x;
    f(x);
    f(s);
    f(t);
  }

}

int main(){
  a::g();
}
```

if `void f(int){}` is defined in namespace a (line 3 is uncommented), it shadows the later definitions of `void f(b::T){}` and `void f(a::S){}`, but not `void f(X){}`.
Why?

Comment: I think it does hide the outer `f`, and that `f(c)` uses `f(int)` when in the same namespace.

Comment: The same thing happens with a struct X instread of char

Comment: No, that's a different thing. If the parameter and the function is declared in the same namespace (including the global namespace), the function is still found.

Comment: @BoPersson thank you!! 
this is exactly the point!

Comment: @BoPersson: if you write it as an answer I'll mark it as definitive answer. In fact, 

namespace c{
  struct Y{};
  void f(Y){}
}

and f(y) works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shadows `f(char)` and `f(int)` will be called, since char can be implicitly casted to int.
http://liveworkspace.org/code/8d7d4e0bc02fd44226921483a910a57b

EDIT.

There is function `f(int)` in namespace A. There is function `f(A::S)` in global namespace. We trying to call f(s) where s is `A::S` from function g, which is in namespace `A`, compiler finds, that function shall apply S `(A::S)`, but there is no such function in namespace `A`, so compiler stops and give error.
http://liveworkspace.org/code/5f989559d2609e57c8b7a655d5b1cebe

There is function `f(B::T)` in global namespace. Trying to find in namespace A `(f(int))` and in namespace B (since arg-type is in namespace B), nothing finded, compiler stops.
http://liveworkspace.org/code/4ebb0374b88b29126f85038026f5e263

There is function `f(X)` in global namespace, `X` is in global namespace, look at namespace A `(f(int))` and in global namespace (find `f(X)`) - all is okay.
http://liveworkspace.org/code/c9ef24db2b5355c4484aa99884601a1a

For more information please read par 3.4.2 of C++ standard (draft n3337). or, more simply http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup

Comment: thank you. I modified the code to show that the same thing happens with a struct which is not convertible to int

Comment: Do you have any idea of why it does not shadow f(X) ?

Comment: But `struct X` is declared in the same namespace as `f(X)`, so other rules applies there. See [Argument Dependent Lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup)