# c++ compiler cant find function overloaded with namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have the following four files,

```
//struct.h
#pragma once
namespace coffee {
    class MD2 {};
    class Recorder{};
    class Book{};
}


//setup.h
#pragma once
#include "struct.h"
void wire(coffee::MD2 md2, coffee::Book book){}

//strategy.h
#pragma once
#include "struct.h"
#include "setup.h"
namespace strategy {
    int wire(coffee::MD2 md2, coffee::Recorder recorder) {}
    int setup(coffee::MD2 md2, coffee::Recorder recorder, coffee::Book book) {
        wire(md2, recorder);
        wire(md2, book); // <--- cant find this function
    }
}

//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "strategy.h"
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

There is not `using namespace X` in header, but the compiler still cant find `wire(md2, book)`, may I please know why?

Comment: `strategy::wire` hides `::wire`.

Comment: @leslie.yao thanks, in this case, if want compiler to find second wire function in setup.h, I should write `::wire(md2, book);?

Comment: Yes, or add `using ::wire;` to make overload resolution working for you.

Comment: See [Shadowing of functions in namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931041/shadowing-of-functions-in-namespaces) and [C++ Declaring function in namespace with same name as function in global namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41686797/12002570) and [Using functions from global namespace in a namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60246803/using-functions-from-global-namespace-in-a-namespace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comments, the `wire` in namespace `strategy` shadows the `wire` included from struct.h. Access that function by prepending with `::`.

For instance, the following prints `foo` rather than `bar::foo`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void foo() {
    std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
}

namespace bar {
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "bar::foo" << std::endl;
    }

    void baz() { ::foo(); }
}

int main() {
    bar::baz();
}
```